# Google Service Account + Drive API unable to set expirationTime (python)

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use a service account and the Google Drive API to automate sharing a folder and i want to be able to set the expirationTime property.

I've found previous threads that mention setting it in a permissions.update() call, but whatever i try i get the same generic error - 'Expiration dates cannot be set on this item.'.

I've validated i'm passing the correct date format, because i've even shared manually from my drive account and then used the permissions.list() to get the expirationTime from the returned data.

I've also tried creating a folder in my user drive, making my service account and editor and then trying to share that folder via API but i get the same problem.

Is there something that prevents a service account being able to set this property?

To note - I haven't enabled the domain wide delegation and tried impersonating yet.

Sample code:

```
update_body = {
    'role': 'reader',
    'expirationTime': '2023-03-13T23:59:59.000Z'
}
driveadmin.permissions().update(
    fileId='<idhere>', permissionId='<idhere>', body=update_body).execute()
```

Comment: are you getting an error? expirationTime is writeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the documentation from the feature it seems that it's only available to paid Google Workspace subscriptions as mentioned in the [`Google Workspace updates blog`](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/10/expiring-access-controls-google-drive.html). You are most likely getting the error `Expiration dates can't be set on this item` as the service account is treated as a regular Gmail account and you can notice that this feature is not available for this type of accounts in the availability section of the update:

[image]

If you perform impersonation with your Google Workspace user I'm pretty sure that you won't receive the error as long as you have one of the subscriptions in which the feature is enabled. You can check more information about how to perform impersonation and Domain Wide Delegation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority).

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thanks for your response. I was also told something similar by my Google Admin team, that the service accounts i'm using are not tied to our Google Workspace subscription.